# Child element doesn't get the hover effect

Tags: html, css

Hi I am making a personal blog and on the page where there is a list of posts, I want to underline the text when the visitor is trying to click a post name.

How can I make to so when they hover the div tag with class "entry" the text under this div tag get underlined?

Here is the link to jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gfz30j6d/

```css
.entry{
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    padding:0;
    height:1rem;
    margin-bottom:1rem
}

.entry:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}

.txt span {
    display:inline-block;
}

.txt :hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
}
    
p{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:1rem;
    margin:0;
    background:lightgrey;
}
    
.post-title {
    float:left; 
    padding-right:5px;
    display: block;
}
    
.post-date {
    float:right; 
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry txt">
  <p class="post-title txt">
    <span>First blog post about something random</span>
  </p>
  <p class="post-date txt">
    <span>25 January</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to be doing that currently. Is it that you just want the text underlined?

Comment: Seems to work in your snippet...

Comment: @UdenduAbasili I want both texts the date and the title to be underlined and the border to be solid, so there is some feedback for the user who is trying the click a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector can just point to a child element, like `.entry:hover p`.

```css
.entry {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  padding: 0;
}

.entry:hover p {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  background: lightgrey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <p class="post-title">
    <span>First blog post about something random</span>
  </p>
  <p class="post-date">
    <span>25 January</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already doing what you want but also with the container div. If you only want the text to be underlined when hovered you have to delete the hover declaration for the container div:

```
.entry:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

and change the hover declaration for the class "txt" to `p.txt` since the class is applied to both the paragraphs and the container div.

**Working example**:

```css
.entry{
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-bottom:1px dotted black;
    padding:0;
    height:1rem;
    margin-bottom:1rem
}

p.txt span {
    display:inline-block;
}

p.txt :hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
}
    
p{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:1rem;
    margin:0;
    background:lightgrey;
}
    
.post-title {
    float:left; 
    padding-right:5px;
    display: block;
}
    
.post-date {
    float:right; 
    padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry txt">
  <p class="post-title txt">
    <span>First blog post about something random</span>
  </p>
  <p class="post-date txt">
    <span>25 January</span>
  </p>
</div>
```